# What is the correct way to instantiate an object in angular through factory?

Tags: angularjs, oop

I recently read the [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and I still wonder what are the good practices for instantiate an Object like this one :

```
Tracker = function(data){
  key: data.key,
  name: data.name,
  buckets: data.buckets,
  enable: data.enable || false,
  geoip: data.geoip || false
}
```

My goals is to respect the principe of decoupling. I don't want any `new Tracker()` in my controller.

Based to the [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) I use a factory to decoupling my controller from the class Tracker. Here is my factory.

```
  angular
  .module('ranger')
  .factory('factoryTracker', factoryTracker);

factoryTracker.$inject = ['$anyInjetable'];

function factoryTracker($anyInjetable) {
  var factory = {
    instantiate: instantiate
  };

  return factory;
  ///////////

  function instantiate(data){
    return {
      //Properties
      key: data.key,
      name: data.name,
      buckets: data.buckets,
      enable: data.enable || false,
      geoip: data.geoip || false
      //Methods
      helloWorld: helloWorld
    };
  }

  function helloWorld(){
      return "I come in peace";
  }
}
```

In my controller I use it with:

```
factoryTracker.instantiate({
                key: tracker._id,
                name: tracker.name,
                enable: false
            });
```

My problem is the way of my Tracker object is declared :

- is not really declared, we only see the implementation
- not easy to read
- implemented methods are outside the object closure...
- Most important: if I want to switch the class to instantiate so I don't want to write it in the factory.

I came to this regarding several sources on using factories and where to put models. But I am not OK with my code for now.

Any advices ?

Comment: Well you can also at this post https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc

Comment: Useful ressource, thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards of the link provided by @Chandermani here is my final code. Clear, net, readable.

```
angular
  .module('ranger')
  .factory('factoryTracker', factoryTracker);

    factoryTracker.$inject = ['$q'];

    function factoryTracker($q) {

        /**
        * Constructor, with class name
        */
        function Tracker(data) {
          // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
          this.key = data.key;
          this.name = data.name;
          this.buckets = data.buckets;
          this.enable = data.enable;
          this.geoip = data.geoip;
        }

        /**
        * Public method, assigned to prototype
        */
        Tracker.prototype.helloWorld = function () {
          return "I come in peace";
        };

        /**
        * Static method, assigned to class
        * Instance ('this') is not available in static context
        */
        Tracker.build = function (data) {
          return new Tracker(data);
        };

        return Tracker;
    }
```